# Read keyvault secrets in Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops, azure-keyvault

I am trying to run npm test in my cicd pipeline and this test needs to read some secrets hence when I try to run  MY_Secret=$(MY-Secret) npm test ; it works as I have defined this secret in my Azure pipeline variable section with its value. But I have few applications with more than 50 secrets and I don't think this is a better solution hence I tried to edit my pipeline in Azure Devops and used Azure Key Vault. I provided the service connection ,key vault and updated my pipeline yaml. But I am still not able to see successful npm test output. I tried to echo one of the secret from my keyvault and I guess I is correct to still show as secret.

---

This is how I tried by adding secret and its value in variable and running MY_Secret=$(MY-Secret) npm test , this works fine https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9E1G.png.
But when I tried using adding azure key vault in azure devops:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLQEc.png

```
- task: AzureKeyVault@2
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: 'keyvaultsp'
    KeyVaultName: 'mykeyvault'
    SecretsFilter: '*'
    RunAsPreJob: true
```

The npm test got failed which needs to read those secrets to pass.

```
Error:
      at Object.isEmpty (/home/vsts/work/1/s/lib/utilities/index.js:495:192)
      at new OTPMAdaptor (/home/vsts/work/1/s/lib/adaptors/communication/otpm.js:23:197)
      at new OtpService (/home/vsts/work/1/s/lib/services/otp.js:13:97)
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)

server.registerService() called by haute using /home/vsts/work/1/s/lib/services/otp.js: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
      at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
      at Object.isEmpty (/home/vsts/work/1/s/lib/utilities/index.js:495:192)
      at new OTPMAdaptor (/home/vsts/work/1/s/lib/adaptors/communication/otpm.js:23:197)
      at new OtpService (/home/vsts/work/1/s/lib/services/otp.js:13:97)
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)

server.registerService() called by haute using /home/vsts/work/1/s/lib/services/otp.js: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
      at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
      at Object.isEmpty (/home/vsts/work/1/s/lib/utilities/index.js:495:192)
      at new OTPMAdaptor (/home/vsts/work/1/s/lib/adaptors/communication/otpm.js:23:197)
      at new OtpService (/home/vsts/work/1/s/lib/services/otp.js:13:97)
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)

server.registerService() called by haute using /home/vsts/work/1/s/lib/services/otp.js: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
      at Function.keys (<anonymous>)
      at Object.isEmpty (/home/vsts/work/1/s/lib/utilities/index.js:495:192)
      at new OTPMAdaptor (/home/vsts/work/1/s/lib/adaptors/communication/otpm.js:23:197)
      at new OtpService (/home/vsts/work/1/s/lib/services/otp.js:13:97)
      at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)

npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
Finishing: Testing
```

Comment: HI Chris; it would be easier to answer your question if you included specific details of how your pipeline is fetching secrets from key vault, and exactly what you see going wrong. Remember, on this site we are encouraged to [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72177260/edit) our questions to make them as clear as possible.

Comment: Hi Vince, I have edited my question with more details.

Comment: Could you paste in the yaml of you task which fetches the secret from key vault? That seems crucial.

Comment: This is how I am fetching secrets.                                                                                 
    - task: AzureKeyVault@2
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'keyvaultsp'
        KeyVaultName: 'mykeyvault'
        SecretsFilter: '*'
        RunAsPreJob: true

Comment: It's worth checking that the secret has been fetched. If you add a powershell task with this script, it will print all the pipeline variables: `Get-ChildItem Env:\ | ForEach-Object {Write-Host "'$($_.Name)':'$($_.Value)'" }` . Secret values will be masked, but it will confirm that the secret variable does exist.

Comment: The secrets are being fetched and I am able to use these secrets in other section of of my cicd yaml. I want to know how can I not mention each secret and its variable while doing npm test.                                                                                                          Right now I have to do ; COSMOS_DB_DATABASEID=$(COSMOS_DB_DATABASEID) COSMOS_DB_ENDPOINT=$(COSMOS-DB-ENDPOINT) npm install. I don't want to pass all secrets like this.

Comment: How is your npm test trying to access the variables? Can you show the yaml for that task perhaps?